# Getting error on bundle install Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extensio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Installing therubyracer 0.12.1 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/local/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling constants.cc
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:60:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:62,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/allocator.h:48:31: error: bits/c++allocator.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cstddef:49: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cstddef:54: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:62,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/functexcept.h:91: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:63,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:74: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:87: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:110: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:125: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:145: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:152: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:159: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:166: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:198: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:205: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:212: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:219: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:226: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:233: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:240: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:247: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:265: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:272: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:279: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:296: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:310: error: ‘__gnu_cxx’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:311: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:355: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:378: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:385: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:392: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:417: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:45: error: ‘__enable_if’ is not a template
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:67: error: ‘__if_type’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:110: error: ‘__if_type’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:158: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:158: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:158: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:163: error: ‘__promote’ is not a template
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:202: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:66: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:69: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:72: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:75: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:101: error: ‘__are_same’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:101: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:101: error: a comma operator cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:101: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:101: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘float’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:101: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:105: error: ‘__are_same’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:105: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:105: error: a comma operator cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:105: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:105: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘float’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:106: error: ‘__are_same’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:106: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:106: error: a comma operator cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:106: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:106: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘float’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:51: error: provided for ‘template struct __conditional_type’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘::’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘,’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: explicit qualification in declaration of ‘__value’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:123: error: template declaration of ‘int __value’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/numeric_traits.h:128: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:60,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/move.h:96: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:146: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:146: error: ‘bool operator==(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:152: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:152: error: ‘bool operator<(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:159: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:159: error: ‘bool operator!=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:165: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:165: error: ‘bool operator>(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:171: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:171: error: ‘bool operator<=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:177: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:177: error: ‘bool operator>=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:214: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:259: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:83: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:165: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:68,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h: In function ‘typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:113: error: ‘__distance’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114: error: ‘__iterator_category’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:119: error: ‘input_iterator_tag’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h: In function ‘void advance(_InputIterator&, _Distance)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:172: error: ‘__advance’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:172: error: ‘__iterator_category’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:195: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:69,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:278: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:279: error: ‘bool operator==(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:284: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:285: error: ‘bool operator<(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:290: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:291: error: ‘bool operator!=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:296: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:297: error: ‘bool operator>(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:302: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:303: error: ‘bool operator<=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:308: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:309: error: ‘bool operator>=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:313: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘reverse_iterator’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:313: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:319: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:328: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:329: error: ‘bool operator==(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:334: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:335: error: ‘bool operator<(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:340: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:341: error: ‘bool operator!=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:346: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:347: error: ‘bool operator>(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:352: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:353: error: ‘bool operator<=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:358: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:359: error: ‘bool operator>=(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:370: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘reverse_iterator’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:370: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:654: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:666: error: ‘std::iterator’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:692: error: ‘__are_same’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:692: error: a comma operator cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:692: error: ‘::__value’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:693: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:45: error: provided for ‘template struct __enable_if’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:693: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:693: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:693: error: expected ‘::’ before ‘&’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:693: error: expected identifier before ‘&’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h: In constructor ‘__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator(const int&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:694: error: request for member ‘base’ in ‘__i’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/debug/debug.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/debug/debug.h:47: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘namespace’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/new:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:60,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:63,
                 from rr.h:6,
                 from constants.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected declaration before end of line
make: *** [constants.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/html/APP/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/html/APP/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
Using slim 3.0.3
Using sort_alphabetical 1.0.2
Using activemodel 3.2.13
Using arbre 1.0.2
Using delayed_job 3.0.5
Using factory_girl 4.8.0
Using jbuilder 2.2.11
Using whenever 0.9.0
Using mail 2.5.4
Using akami 1.2.1
Using axlsx 2.0.0
Using axiom-types 0.0.5
Using coercible 0.2.0
Using wasabi 3.2.3
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.

---

Adding details of gcc version

~~~~gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)

Answer (score 1):

try installing `gcc` with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: and what about `build-essential`?

Comment: Its a RHEL. We used : 
yum install gcc

Comment: In my case the issue was that gcc was installed but g++ was  not. In RedHat we fixed the issue by `yum install gcc-g++`